# Torch install without curl

Tags: shell, curl, permissions, torch

I need to install Torch on server,

but its installation guide requires the following line as the first step:

```
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torch/ezinstall/master/install-deps | bash
```

curl is not installed on my server, and I'm not the root, so I don't have permission to install it.

I downloaded the script file in the URL, and chmod-ed it,

but can't execute it, again due to permission.

Is there a way to install torch without usage of curl?

```
bash install-deps
```

resulted in

```
xxxx is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Torch dependencies needs to be installed -  if you install it via this script, that'll require root privileges.

If you saved the script, you can start it (without chmod) with

```
bash install-deps
```

Comment: it returns the following: xxx is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.

Comment: That means you need root privileges (on Ubuntu, Fedora and others), the script assumes you have sudo preconfigured with your userid xxx to gain elevated privileges for dependency installation. On Ubuntu (not sure what distro you use), for example, the default `/etc/sudoers` file has:

    # Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
    %admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
As root, add your userid to the admin group: `usermod -a -G admin xxx`

Comment: I'm on a shared server, so I can't add myself to admin group.

Comment: Then you won't be able to perform that installation, I think - you'll need the assistance of the admin of your server.